# Durbin Watson test on the residuals of a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-models, temporal, autocorrelation

I am trying to calculate the temporal autocorrelation of a poison distributed mixed model, and was wondering how to do so. I get an error that says "$ operator not defined for this S4 class"  I can successfully run the the dwtest on a linear model, with a poisson distribution, but not the one I really want.

Successful model and code:

```
temp.nem.cuc.glm<-glm(AllDat$nem.cuc~ AllDat$year.collected, family=poisson(link="log"))
summary(temp.nem.cuc.lm) 
time<-AllDat$year.collected
dwnem.cuc<-dwtest(temp.nem.cuc.lm, order.by = time, alternative = "two.sided", iterations = 50, exact = FALSE, tol = 1e-10)
dwnem.cuc
```

Unsuccessful model and code

```
#the model I am really interested in
nem.cuc.pois=glmer(nem.cuc~ I(year.collected-1930)+I(standard.length..mm./100) + (1|sites1), family = "poisson", data=AllDat)
time<-AllDat$year.collected
dwnemresid.cuc<-dwtest(nem.cuc.pois, order.by = time, alternative = "two.sided", iterations = 50, exact = FALSE, tol = 1e-10)
dwnem.cuc
```

Comment: what package is `dwtest` from?  Can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: Please don't e-mail me stuff from StackOverflow (unless particularly requested). Instead, post your reproducible example by editing your question.

Comment: dwtest is part of the lmtest package.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I found the "check_autocorrelation" function from the performance package, but it returns only whether it detected autocorrelation or not.

I would also be interested in finding a DW test that returns a statistic, if anyone knows one - or in a way to solve the S4 class error, since I encounter it repeatedly.